# Is there a way to have two X axis labels in chart js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chart.js

Is there any way to have two seperate labels for my two x axis's? I want the top X axis to have labels of age, but I want to have the bottom X axis to have labels of Race. How do I do this

Code:

```
const data = {
    labels: ['Younger Than 18', '18-30', '31-45', 'Older than 45', 'Unknown'],
    
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Races/Ethnicities Killed',
        data: [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 0],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
        tension: 0.4,
        yAxisID: 'y'     
    }, 
    {
        label: 'Ages Killed',
        data: [10, 22, 36, 49, 52, 63, 79],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 26, 104, 1)',
        tension: 0.4,
    }]
};

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left'
          },
          x2: {
            position: 'top'
          },
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('chart'),
      config
    );

    // Instantly assign Chart.js version
    const chartVersion = document.getElementById('chartVersion');
    chartVersion.innerText = Chart.version;
```